# Custom domain with Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, subscription, branding

Is there any nice component for Joomla 1.0.x allowing to serve custom domains? What I am trying to archieve is to sell subscription to my service and to offer custom branding including custom urls like yourcompany.myservice.com and even example.myservice.com. Any pointers? I am selling subscriptions themselves already for a long time, so the question is specifically on the domain part - how to manage apache vhosts/dns settings/whatever dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Joomla has moved on with version 1.5 it would be hard to find what you want for 1.0. I'd recommend switching to 1.5.

You can easily get multi-domain ability yourself. First you have to make sure all sub domains resolve to the same set of IPs. (*.yoursite.com)

For 1.0 you could probably get away with just plugins, but you might need to edit the core.
If you use a plugin, say a system plugin, in the plugin you can check for the HOST header.

eg:

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

From this, you base your specific settings/parameters etc. You can also do the check from within components, modules etc.

An example would be loading different template. If the host is a sub domain, then load a custom template for that sub domain.

This is actually a lot easier to do with 1.5 as you can control what loads from plugins.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately switching to 1.5 is difficult as it is basically about reimplementing the website, but this approach will help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the apache config. There are several Plugins that can choose the Joomla configuration (including the template) and database based on the Domain name e.g. [Joomla Multisites](http://www.jms2win.com/) (btw. I would really recommend switching to 1.5)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but I don't think I need different sites - it is more about sending users from different domains to the same site with only minor variances. But will check more of course.

Comment: Well these Plugins basically do what bucabay mentioned. If you need it more personalised you actually should prefer the programatical way. I can guess, that it is a lot of work to switch to the newer version but i really think switching to 1.5 will be worth it on the long run...